# Android Studio Rendering: "high_quality" in attribute "breakStrategy" is not a valid integer

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

> Rendering Problems
>
> "high_quality" in attribute "breakStrategy" is not a valid integer
>
> ([N] similar errors not shown)
>
> Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

([N] is a variable number.)

This message was produced after I restarted Android Studio, for **all activities** and **any other design-able files** (such `xml/pref_XXX.xml` files)!

I searched all project files (Ctrl+Shift+F) for "high_quality" and "breakStrategy" but found nothing!

The interesting note is no problem in designing! Just show this message.

Also, I tried `Clean Project`, `Rebuild Project`, `Synchronize (Ctrl+Alt+Y)`, `Synchronize app`, pressing the `refresh` hyperlink inside the mentioned message, restarting Android Studio again, ... But no avail!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the android sdk build-tools, platfom-tools, API 25 and works.